# Hooking a system call sys_open in linux kernel module

Tags: c, linux, kernel-module

I'm trying hook system call sys_open() in linux kernel module with ftrace_hook, but sys_open() didn't work. insmod gives no errors, but the function fh_sys_open() is not even called

https://github.com/ilammy/ftrace-hook

Other system calls working norm (sys_execve(), sys_copy()...).

Kernel version 4.19.0-6-amd64

In other kernel version this code working

Here is the piece of code

```
static asmlinkage long (*real_sys_open)(const char __user *filename, int flags,
                           umode_t mode);

static asmlinkage long fh_sys_open(const char __user *filename, int flags,
                           umode_t mode)
{
        long ret;
        char *kernel_filename;

        /* Copy buffer to kernel space from user space */
        kernel_filename = duplicate_filename(filename);

        /* Add new event to list */
        add_event(kernel_filename, &events_f);

        kfree(kernel_filename);

        /* Call original function */
        ret = real_sys_open(filename, flags, mode);

        return ret;
}

/*
 * x86_64 kernels have a special naming convention for syscall entry points in newer kernels.
 * That's what you end up with if an architecture has 3 (three) ABIs for system calls.
 */
#ifdef PTREGS_SYSCALL_STUBS
#define SYSCALL_NAME(name) ("__x64_" name)
#else
#define SYSCALL_NAME(name) (name)
#endif

#define HOOK(_name, _function, _original)   \
    {                                       \
        .name = SYSCALL_NAME(_name),        \
        .function = (_function),            \
        .original = (_original),            \
    }



static struct ftrace_hook demo_hooks[] = {
        HOOK("sys_open", fh_sys_open,  &real_sys_open)
};
```

Comment: During the sys_open() call, my fh_sys_open() function must be called first, and this function already calls the original function

Comment: real_sys_open() points to the sys_open() function

Comment: This piece of code show tells nothing about Linux kernel facilities used for hook: `ftrace_hook` is neither a core function nore a function from widely known sources (I would treat the repo with 12 commits and the single blogpost as widely known sources). This is not how Stack Overflow works: we want the whole **relevant code** to be in **the question post**. Please, add relevant code to the question post. Ideally, we want [mcve]. That is, if you find that `fh_ftrace_thunk` function is not called by itself, no needs to check hook function call. See also [ask].